# Basic proxy-authorization header for HTTPS URLs does not get passed in the header in jdk 1.8

Tags: java, https, proxy, basic-authentication, tunnel

I am trying to connect to a HTTPS URL from my java program through a proxy. The proxy server is also created by me using jetty library which runs in a different machine. In my proxy server I need to validate the incoming Proxy-Authorization header in my ConnectHandler. However I am not to get the Proxy-Authorization header passed with Https URL.

My code is as follows:

```
    String https_url = "https://www.google.com/";
    URL url;
    try {
        String host = "my-proxy-server.com";
        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(host, 8888);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);

        url = new URL(https_url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(new String("admin" + ":" + "admin").getBytes("UTF-8")));

        con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", authHeader);

        con.connect();
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my jetty based proxy server's ConnectHandler, I am printing out the headers and Proxy-Authorization is not one of the headers. It only prints the following header, Accept, User-Agent, Host, Proxy-Connection

I have tried all potential solutions in other stackoverflow posts, the most common being running the program with the following env variable, but it still doesnt work.

```
java  -Dhttp.auth.preference=basic -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
```

Also I have updated it in jre/lib/net.properties

```
jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
```

I have also tried the approach to set the default authenticator

```
    Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            if (getRequestorType().equals( RequestorType.PROXY )) {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( userid, password.toCharArray() );
            }
            return super.getPasswordAuthentication();
        }
    });
```

}

With above approach getPasswordAuthentication does not get called during the initial CONNECT request to the proxy. If I hack my proxy server to return true in the handleAuthentication of my CONNECT Handler even if the proxy authorization header is not found, then I noticed getPasswordAuthentication gets called during actual call to htts://www.google.com, after the CONNECT response has returned.

Debugging through the decompiled code it seems, ***AuthenticationInfo.getProxyAuth*** is returning null which is why the proxy authorization header is not set. The AuthCache which is backed up by a Hashtable is empty. However not sure how this AuthCache is populated.

I am using JDK 1.8
java version "1.8.0_202"

Any help greatly appreciated.